# Order of output in Windows batch files

Tags: windows, batch-file, io, stdio

When I execute the following batch file

```
@echo off
echo Text from echo
xcopy foobarium
```

I get the following output:

```
File not found - foobarium
0 File(s) copied
Text from echo
```

Obiously the order of the outputs is swapped. How can I ensure that the output appears in the order the commands are specified in?

(This is on Win7)

Comment: There's no way you are getting this output from this code if no external factors come into play. Check your assumptions.

Comment: I get the expected order in Win 8.1 32 bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this is a bug in [clink](http://code.google.com/p/clink) (a utility that provides bash-like auto-completion for cmd.exe). I've filed a [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/clink/issues/detail?id=157).